# What event is fired when detail page tab is clicked

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In LEX, I need to know what event is fired when a user clicks a tab that is on the lightning record page.  Right now we have multiple tabs that contain lightning components.  Since the component is rendered the first time the tab is clicked, if a user goes to another tab and makes modifications that should be reflected in another tab then, when they click back into the other tab the component is still showing old data.

Comment: Did you get solution for this?

Comment: is this custom tabs or standard tabs?